# Text in legend for matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a plot and want a legend placed in the upper right corner without any frame around with two lines:

```
a = 10
b = 3*pi
```

Those lines are some coefficients of my plotted function.

So far, I have

```
ax1.plot(x, y, label='a')
ax1.legend(["a = 10", "b = 3*pi"], loc="upper right", ncol=1, frameon=False)
```

But that keeps lines type or color next to my two strings. How to remove them?
Put it in the title is not an option. There is a different text.

Comment: Why not just add two text labels with `ax.text()`?

Comment: @OliverW., I tried `ax1.text(.6, .06, r'Hello')`. It doesn't work. And `ax1.annotate('text', xytext=(.6, .06))` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `text` method of the axes object.
Also, remember that the default is that the first 2 arguments of `ax1.text` are in *data coordinates*, so in your example, `Hello` will be put at `(x,y)=(.6, .06)`, unless you also add the parameter `transform=ax1.transAxes` to `ax1.text`, like so:

```
ax1.text(.60, .06, r'Hello', transform=ax1.transAxes)
```

That will add the text label a little over halfway from the left and a little higher than the bottom of the axes.